# Start an activity in backround by using ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want to start an activity in backround (even if the app is killed) by using ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION. It works only when the app is in the foreground. My code is below;

1.Manifest File

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

 <receiver
        android:name=".digitalclock.DigitalClockReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

2-BroadcastReceiver

```
 override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

    if (intent?.action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {

     
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
            val intent2 = Intent(context, DigitalClockActivity::class.java)
            intent2.putExtra("unlock_screen", true)
            intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            context?.startActivity(intent2)
        } 

        }
    }
```

I also started a service in Broadcast and it receives always the intent-filter even if the app is killed. Service class also starts but activity not.

Comment: where are you using `ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION` in code as written in your question?

Comment: I have a switch (default false) , if the user want to switch to true he must grant permission, then the property will be enabled, so I do this work in related activity. If the property is not enabled then the Broadcast will never work in my code.

Comment: so your broadcast receiver is getting fired but activity not starting?

Comment: yes, exactly , activity doesn't start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
val intent2 = Intent(context, DigitalClockActivity::class.java)
```

with hardcoded package and class name

```
val i = Intent();
i.setClassName("com.test", "com.test.DigitalClockActivity")
```

Change package and activity class name to your own!

Comment: It works when the app is in the backround but it works only on an emulator when the app is killed not on a real device.

Comment: @Ahmet have u tested on real device after replacing as written in my answer?what android version your device has?

Comment: yes I have tested on a real Xiaomi device (API 29) , it works fine on Android emulator (API 29)

Comment: @Ahmet first uninstall app from your real device.then make changes written in my answer and then reinstall on your real device

Comment: I removed by "adb uninstall com.xxx.xxx" but unfortunately it didn't work. What else can I edo?

Comment: @Ahmet Check logcat for any crash..debug and check if your startactivity code getting called

Comment: I have checked  by using a log message after setContentView() , still not working

Comment: U getting log message after setcontentview in logcat?

Comment: yes, on emulator I am getting log messages, only when the app is killed on my real device (Xiaomi) there is no log messages

Comment: I am asking about real device only in which you facing issue..check by debugging that whether your startactivity is called on real device..nd if there is any crash